# Fitting caption width to table width using nicematrix package

Tags: captions, nicematrix, floatrow

I'm very much a LaTeX beginner and searching for possibilities to include footnotes below tables, I came across the [nicematrix](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) package. This package combines basically everthing I need to generate tables in my document. The only thing I'm missing is the possibility to fit the caption width to the table width. I tried using the package [floatrow](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) that is mentioned in the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package manual, but that messes up the table footnotes generated by NiceMatrix (they simply do no longer appear in the document).
Since the table footnotes are already fitted to the table width, I was hoping there might be a similar way to achieve this. For most tables, this isn't an issue as the caption is smaller in width than the table anyway, but in the example shown below, it doesn't look to good for my taste.

The entire document is compiled using LuaLaTeX, but I don't think it is mandatory here.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading,captions=figuresignature]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{caption} [2022/02/20]
\captionsetup{%
    format=hang,%
    labelsep=period%
    }
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{%
    cell-space-limits = 2pt,%
    notes/code-before = \footnotesize%
    }
        
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{%
    S[%
        table-number-alignment = center,%
        table-format = #1%
        ]%
    }
        
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{This is a long long long caption that needs to be fitted to the
        table width}
    \label{tab:Activity}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}l!{\qquad}@{}A{1.1e1}!{\qquad}A{1.1e1}@{}}
        \toprule
        \Block{2-1}{Nuclide}    & \Block{1-2}{Maximal activity in \unit{Bq}}  \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
                                & {Material~1}                 & {Material~2} \\
        \midrule
        $^{99}\mathrm{Tc}$\tabularnote{This is a long long long tabular note
                that is already fitted to the table width.}
                                & 10.1e9                       & 1.1e5        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help realizing what I'm trying to achieve?

Furthermore, since I'm a LaTeX beginner, feel free to mention and correct stupid things I've done in the code above.

Thank you very much,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v 6.12 of 2022-07-28) provides a key 'caption' for a caption that will be wrapped at the width of the tabular.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrreprt}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}  

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{%
    cell-space-limits = 2pt,
    notes/code-before = \footnotesize ,
    caption-above 
}

\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{%
    S[%
    table-number-alignment = center,%
    table-format = #1%
    ]%
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\label{tab:Activity}

\begin{NiceTabular}
  [caption = {This is a long long long caption that needs to be fitted to the table width}]
  {@{}l!{\qquad}@{}A{1.1e1}!{\qquad}A{1.1e1}@{}}
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{Nuclide} & \Block{1-2}{Maximal activity in \unit{Bq}}  \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
& {Material~1}       & {Material~2} \\
\midrule
$^{99}\mathrm{Tc}$\tabularnote{This is a long long long tabular note that is already fitted to the table width.} & 10.1e9 & 1.1e5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]